# border-radius antialiasing problems on Android

Tags: android, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android WebView border-radius aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338577/android-webview-border-radius-aliasing)

I'm using phonegap to build an android app and the border-radius (and its friends -moz-border-radius and -webkit-border-radius) all result in really crappy looking rounded corners.  It looks very pixelated around the edges to the point where its pointless to use because it looks so bad beyond a 3 pixel radius.

I've seen posts from about 6 months ago on here that mentioned that there was no way to solve this.  I was wondering if anything has changed since.  I'd like to use CSS3 instead of images for rounded corners, but I can't if it looks as bad as it does now.  Any ideas or workarounds?