# css transform, jagged edges in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, transform, antialiasing

I've been using CSS3 transform to rotate images and textboxes with borders in my website.

The problem is that the border look jagged in Chrome, like a (low-resolution) game without Anti-Aliasing. In IE, Opera and FF it looks much better because AA is used (which is still clearly visible but not that bad). I can't test Safari because I don't own a Mac.

The rotated photo and text itself look fine, it is only the border that looks jagged.

The CSS I use is this:

```
.rotate2deg {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this, e.g. by forcing Chrome to use AA?

Example below:

[image: Jagged Edges example]

Comment: For those reading it later: it should be fixed in Chrome as of version 15 (Nov 2011), but Safari introduced the exact same issue in 5.1 for Mac which is as of now not yet fixed

Comment: And they fixed it so well, that going back is impossible. We have cases where antialiasing is the last thing we want, but now Chrome/Chromium/Safari has no method to turn off antialiasing in transformed images although they are 1-bit images (eg. b/w gif). Blur is so cool, so cool, more blur is more cool, they say! Only way to ensure crisp edges is to convert all to svg paths or objects and add attribute shape-rendering="crispEdges".

Comment: For me the issue is with transparent borders used to create an arrow. This is in Chrome 40 on win and mac.  None of the options here fix the issue.

Answer (score 409, accepted):

In case anyone's searching for this later on, a nice trick to get rid of those jagged edges on CSS transformations in Chrome is to add the CSS property `-webkit-backface-visibility` with a value of `hidden`. In my own tests, this has completely smoothed them out.

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Lifesaver - this trick has allowed us to re-enable -webkit-transform on a number of sites that previously we were forced to turn transforms off because of anti-aliasing issues. Thanks!

Comment: any help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox ?

Comment: Does anyone know how this compares to -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d ?  They seem to have identical results...

Comment: This works in Chrome, but it makes them jagged again in iOS 6!

Comment: @jstafford: I don't get the smoothing with `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d` in Chrome...

Comment: @lazd to fix it in iOS add `padding: 1px; -webkit-background-clip: content-box;`

Comment: Also seems to fix a problem I had with Gifs not rendering properly in chrome - quite bizarre! Thank you, I never would have found this.

Comment: This removes jagged edge for me in iOS7

Comment: Removes the jagged edges for me on Android 4.3.3 Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: If you've an img as a child of the rotated image... jagged edges come back. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429265

Comment: This is also fixing jagged edges on a png with transparent background to which _no_ transform was applied.

Comment: Also fixes misplaced borders when centering something vertically with `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`. Perfect.

Comment: Good to know. But the picture is a bit blured now :\
Better than the jagged of course :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I googled, found this question, saw your answer, tried it, and it worked.  It's beyond me why this works (yet), but it does.  Wonder where this is documented.  Thanks!

Comment: It fixes the issue with jagged edges, but it causes text and images to blur.

Comment: @RobFletcher added padding and background-clip which seem, per this thread, essential to a cross-browser and cross-os solution. This fixes my OSX/Chrome issue too so... I think a complete solution would be something like: `padding: 1px;-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;backface-visibility:hidden;-webkit-background-clip:content-box;background-clip:content-box;`

Comment: this didn't work for me. But Lazd method of adding padding worked. But funny enough, when I use @BenjaminLuoma technique and removed the padding, it worked. Weird

Answer (score 131):

If you are using `transition` instead of `transform`, `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` does not work. A jagged edge appears during animation for a transparent png file.

To solve it I used: `outline: 1px solid transparent;`

Comment: this seems to help out in situations where the web-kit-backface-visibility property missed out.

Comment: Works for me when none of the others did. Before adding this property, Chrome Android had issues. Now all browsers seem to work properly.

Comment: Works for me in Safari on iOS 8.

Comment: Perfect solution. The others didn't work. I almost gave up, and was doubting this would work. But it does!

Comment: *Queue Handel's Messiah*

Comment: Works perfectly for my needs. I am indeed using transition, and the other answers were causing my PNG to become pixelated at its default state. Your answer helped remove any pixelization -- on both default state and during the transition. Perfect!

Comment: this is much better than the accepted answer, as it ... does not hide the backfaces!

Comment: just to throw in my $0.02, this did it for me too :D

Comment: 7 Years later and this answer sadly still works and is still required (from what I've tried)

Answer (score 28):

Adding a 1px transparent border will trigger anti-aliasing

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

Alternatively, add a 1px transparent box-shadow.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

Comment: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) is probably better

Comment: Adding the top section of CSS in your answer and the `outline: 1px solid transparent;` worked well for me. The other solutions above did not work well enough.

Comment: `outline: 1px solid transparent;` trigger anti-aliasing also in Firefox 52 (that has the same troubles of Chrome)

Answer (score 20):

Try 3d transform. This works like a charm!

```
/* Due to a bug in the anti-liasing*/
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);
```

Comment: trying this in chrome now (August 2013 on a Mac), the accepted solution isn't working, but using this (specifically `preserve-3d`; `rotate` can still be used without changing to `rotateZ`) does.

Comment: Super hacky, but worked for me. Try even a smaller degree like 0.05 to avoid a visible miss-alignment.

Comment: preserve-3d saved my life.

Answer (score 16):

I've tried all the solutions here and didn't work in my case. But using

```
will-change: transform;
```

fixes the jagged issue.

Comment: This is the only working solution on chrome 97 (not sure when it start)

Comment: Never heard of this. Thanks, that worked out just perfect.

Comment: The only working solution on iPhone!

Comment: This helped me as well, Chrome 114, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Chosen answer (nor any of the other answers) didn't work for me, but this did:
`img {outline:1px solid transparent;}`

Answer (score 2):

I've been having an issue with a CSS3 gradient with -45deg. The `background` slanted, was badly jagged similar to but worse than the original post. So I started playing with both the `background-size`. This would stretch out the jaggedness, but it was still there. Then in addition I read that other people are having issues too at 45deg increments so I adjusted from `-45deg` to `-45.0001deg` and my problem was solved.

In my CSS below, `background-size` was initially `30px` and the `deg` for the background gradient was exactly `-45deg`, and all keyframes were `30px 0`.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes progressStripeLTR {
        to {
            background-position: 60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-moz-keyframes progressStripeLTR {
        to {
            background-position: 60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-ms-keyframes progressStripeLTR {
        to {
            background-position: 60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-o-keyframes progressStripeLTR {
        to {
            background-position: 60px 0;
        };
    }

    @keyframes progressStripeLTR {
        to {
            background-position: 60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes progressStripeRTL {
        to {
            background-position: -60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-moz-keyframes progressStripeRTL {
        to {
            background-position: -60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-ms-keyframes progressStripeRTL {
        to {
            background-position: -60px 0;
        };
    }

    @-o-keyframes progressStripeRTL {
        to {
            background-position: -60px 0;
        };
    }

    @keyframes progressStripeRTL {
        to {
            background-position: -60px 0;
        };
    }

    .pro-bar-candy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;

        -webkit-border-radius:  3px;
        -moz-border-radius:     3px;
        border-radius:          3px;

        background: rgb(187, 187, 187);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(
                        -45.0001deg,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 25%,
                        transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 75%,
                        transparent 75%,
                        transparent
                    );
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
                        -45.0001deg,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 25%,
                        transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 75%,
                        transparent 75%,
                        transparent
                    );
        background: -o-linear-gradient(
                        -45.0001deg,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 25%,
                        transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 75%,
                        transparent 75%,
                        transparent
                    );
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(
                        -45.0001deg,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 25%,
                        transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 75%,
                        transparent 75%,
                        transparent
                    );
        background: linear-gradient(
                        -45.0001deg,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 25%,
                        transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 50%,
                        rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00) 75%,
                        transparent 75%,
                        transparent
                    );
        background: -webkit-gradient(
                        linear,
                        right bottom,
                        right top,
                        color-stop(
                            25%,
                            rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            25%,
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            50%,
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            50%,
                            rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            75%,
                            rgba(187, 187, 187, 1.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            75%,
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)
                        ),
                        color-stop(
                            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)
                        )
                    );

        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        -webkit-background-size:    60px 60px;
        -moz-background-size:       60px 60px;
        -o-background-size:         60px 60px;
        background-size:            60px 60px;
        }

    .pro-bar-candy.candy-ltr {
        -webkit-animation:  progressStripeLTR .6s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:     progressStripeLTR .6s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation:      progressStripeLTR .6s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:       progressStripeLTR .6s linear infinite;
        animation:          progressStripeLTR .6s linear infinite;
        }

    .pro-bar-candy.candy-rtl {
        -webkit-animation:  progressStripeRTL .6s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:     progressStripeRTL .6s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation:      progressStripeRTL .6s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:       progressStripeRTL .6s linear infinite;
        animation:          progressStripeRTL .6s linear infinite;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following on the div surrounding the element in question fixed this for me.

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

The jagged edges were appearing around the video window in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to mask the jagging using blurred [box-shadows](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/). Using -webkit-box-shadow instead of box-shadow will make sure it doesn't affect non-webkit browsers. You might want to check Safari and the mobile webkit browsers though.

The result is somewhat better, but still a lot less good then with the other browsers:

[image: with box shadow (underside)]

Answer (score 1):

Just thought that we'd throw in our solution too as we had the exact same problem on Chrome/Windows.

We tried the solution by @stevenWatkins above, but still had the "stepping".

Instead of

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

We used:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: initial;
```

For us this did the trick

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the perspective CSS property that did the trick:

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

Completely illogical in my case as I use no 3d transitions, but works nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

### For canvas in Chrome (Version 52)

All listed answers is about images. But my issue is about canvas in chrome (v.52) with transform rotate. They became jagged and all this methods can't help.

Solution that works for me:

1. Make canvas larger on 1 px for each side => +2 px for width and height;
2. Draw image with offset + 1px (in position 1,1 instead of 0,0) and fixed size (size of image should be 2px less than size of canvas)
3. Apply required rotation

**So important code blocks:**

```js
// Unfixed version
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 335, 218);
// Fixed version
ctx.drawImage(img, 1, 1, 335, 218);
```

```css
/* This style should be applied for fixed version */
canvas {
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top:-1px;
}
```

```html
<!--Unfixed version-->
<canvas width="335" height="218"></canvas>
<!--Fixed version-->
<canvas width="337" height="220"></canvas>
```

**Sample:** https://jsfiddle.net/tLbxgusx/1/

*Note: there is a lot of nested divs because it is simplified version from my project.*

---

This issue is reproduced **also for Firefox** for me.
There is no such issue on Safari and FF with retina.

And **other founded solution** is to place canvas into div of same size and apply following css to this div:

```
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0);
// Or
//outline:1px solid transparent;
```

And rotation should be applied to this wrapping div. So listed solution is worked but with small modification.

And modified example for such solution is: https://jsfiddle.net/tLbxgusx/2/

*Note: See style of div with class 'third'.*

Answer (score 0):

For safari 16.2 any of mention solution doesn't work. But I tried rotation and it fix the issue.

```
 transform: "rotatex(360deg)"
```

In my case I have problem with video element.