# css background-image w/ background-color shows artifact border in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, visual-artifacts

I am trying to use a transparent `.png` as a background-image so that I can dynamically use any color I need to, to change the color of the "icon".

I have a .png that is 40px x 40px.  I apply it to a div using background-image, then I give that same div a background-color:

```
.icon {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-image:url('../images/ico.png');
    background-color:#999999;
}
```

This normally works fine, so I'm not sure what's going on with this. Here's a screen shot of what I see in Mac and on PC (respectively) in latest version of Chrome:

Mac[image]

PC[image]

EDIT: [Here's a stripped down version](http://412webdesigns.com/playground/stackoverflow/dev/) of the site, which shows the problem I'm having:

I tried making a fiddle ([here it is anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/dnovjoj9/)), but the fiddle shows perfectly in chrome, just not on my actual site.  I'm not using percentages for this or anything and I'm using the native size for the background - does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: If in the fiddle works ... how do you expect us can solve the problem ? Maybe share also the link to your website

Comment: @danko I've edited the question to show a stripped down version of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to the div with your image background (.info .img in your case).

You are using transform on a parent element, and Chrome does strange things with backface and transformed elements.

I'll link a somewhat relevant answer, though it was an answer to a slightly different problem: [css transform, jagged edges in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome)

Comment: Very nice, I've never seen this before!

Answer (score 1):

The transform you have on .info is what is messing with it.  Instead of using percentages, try:

```
    .info{
        transform: translate(0px,-3px);
```

Comment: You are very correct in saying the percentages in the transform is what was messing it up.  Unfortunately, I have to use percentages for this specific application.