# Achieve irregular rectangular shape image masking in html css

Tags: html, image, css, masking

Is it possible to achieve such an effect in HTML5 and CSS3 , Please find the attached image [image]

Here I have two divs with overflow:hidden, inside each is an image. And when I hover each image, the image zoom in or moves up or down inside this same div container. So basically the div works like a mask for the big image.

What I fail to achieve here is the shape of the div to mask the image. Is there a way to achieve that and can work in the latest versions of almost all browsers?

Thanks for you help !

Comment: You can use the CSS3 `transform` property to match the shape of your image.
https://jsfiddle.net/otv7kfm6/

Comment: What is your code? How do you achieve what you have right now?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I have not achieved this yet, this is an image I just created for the question. I tried a few solutions like CSS trasform and svg but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like that, I would suggest two different possibilities:

- Using CSS transformations (in particular [skewY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)); or
- Using SVG (with just some [polygons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon))

Each of them has some good/bad things and will work in all the modern browsers and in mobile, as you can see in the caniuse.com website for [transform](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

**Using CSS 2D Transformations**

You would have a container `div` that would be skewed vertically, and then inside of it other `div`s with the skew (over)corrected. Then hiding the overflow so the excess of the contained `div`s is not shown.

You can see a demo here (or on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wy06f93m/)):

```css
#skewed {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
 -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg);
 -moz-transform: skewY(-2deg);
 -o-transform: skewY(-2deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    background:black;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#skewed div {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    transform: skewY(4deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewY(4deg);
 -moz-transform: skewY(4deg);
 -o-transform: skewY(4deg);
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.4;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    z-index:1;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#skewed div:hover {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:2;
    background-size:110% 110%;
}

#top {
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/animals) no-repeat center center;
}

#bottom {
    top:150px;
    left:0;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/people) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="skewed">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

About this solution:

- Supported by all major browsers (except Opera Mini), although you'll need to use prefixes.
- Easy to implement and extend with further content (text, links, etc.)
- In Chrome, the edges look too sharp. Although this can be fixed using `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` as [suggested by Neven in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898097/3695983).

---

**Using SVG**

Use `polygon`s to define the basic shapes that you want to create.

I am not a SVG-expert, so I can't do anything fancy, but this is to get a general idea. Here is a simple demo (you can also see it on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8urpqqut/)):

```css
polygon {
    opacity:0.4;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}

polygon:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="300">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/animals" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="img2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="300">
            <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/people" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="300" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon id="top" points="0,20 500,0 500,170 0,130" fill="url(#img1)" />
    <polygon id="bottom" points="0,130 500,170 500,280 0,300" fill="url(#img2)" />
</svg>
```

About this solution:

- Supported by all the major browsers (no need for prefixes or anything)
- Highly customizable: I used polygons, but you could use paths and curves to give a more personal solution.
- SVG is not as easy as the other solution (Ok, something as simple as this is easy, but something more complex will require some learning).