# Logo becomes pixelated when it spins

Tags: html, css

http://jasperalani.com/
If you hover over the logo at the bottom left of the page it becomes super pixelated when you hover over it.

I am using

```css
transform: rotate(360deg);
```

How can I fix this so it maintains its quality?

Comment: The browser does that so save ressources afaik

Comment: did you try `outline: none; ` in your logo css?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are  making you `image` to `transform:rotate(360deg);`, instead of that target you `parent` element `.socialmedia` and try it works.

```
.socialmedia {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 1;
    width:21px;
    height:21px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
.socialmedia:hover{
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```css
.socialmedia {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 1;
 width:21px;
 height:21px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
.socialmedia:hover{
 transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="socialmedia">
 <a href="https://ello.co/jasperalani">
 <img id="ello" src="http://jasperalani.com/images/ello_icon.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is really better than my solution, nice. +1

Comment: Yes @modiX and thanks, because when we rotate our image without any kind of hover effect on it and then you check, it's border still pixelate. Whereas not when placing them in div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known problem on Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome).

Usually, you can overcome the problem by adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to your element you rotate. In your example it will remove the anti aliasing entirely, though.

This is, because you are using `transition` instead of `transform`, so to fix the problem you rather add `outline: 1px solid transparent` to the CSS of your image. This will solve the problem.

```css
img {
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
  }

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<img id="ello" src="http://jasperalani.com/images/ello_icon.png">
```