# How can I fix this CSS bug border-image?

Tags: css

I came across with some CSS bug when added `border-image` and then rotated it. After rotation on border image, we could see additional lines, how could I remove it. Without rotation all look good.

```
height: 96px;
width: 260px;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table;
border: 26px solid transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-border-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/border.jpg) 48 stretch;
border-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/border.jpg) 48 stretch;
-webkit-transition: all ease-in .3s;
transition: all ease-in .3s;
background-color: #cad584;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
transform: rotate(-2deg);
position: relative;
```

It is the result [image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) ideally with the actual image.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also you refer to `translate` in your text but `rotate` in your code.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's the way that CSS items get rotated. It's to do with anti-aliasing. Best way, is to save the image in it's rotated state.

Comment: Some ideas in this thread you can try.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have mentioned, you're seeing anti-aliasing on the edges of the jpeg, which has a solid background colour.

Instead, use a PNG with alpha transparency, that way there is no visible edge to anti-alias.

You'll need to find some way to stop your background colour showing through the border - in the example below I've simply wrapped it with an outer div that gets the border image. There are probably more elegant solutions!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Work for Us</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
border-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/border-with-alpha.png) 48 stretch;
```

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ktxcs2c8/1/

Forgive my terrible border image, and huge data URL!

Answer (score 0):

Try `transform: rotate(-2deg); translateZ(1px);`

Leave `translateZ(1px)` the same even though you are varying the degrees rotated.

```
transform: rotate(-10deg); translateZ(1px);
transform: rotate(-4deg); translateZ(1px);
transform: rotate(6deg); translateZ(1px);
```