# Disable antialias on HTML elements with transform: rotate() in Webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, antialiasing, image-rotation

Say I want to render this picture with no anti-aliasing using HTML elements:

[image: square]

I thought of making a square div, and then rotate it 45 degrees. But doing so will smooth out the edges, like this:

[image: smoothSquare]

I managed to bypass this only on Firefox by using `transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(45deg);`, but I'd like to do the same on Webkit.

**[How I made the square](https://jsfiddle.net/86znogtv/)**

Comment: Would be great to see how you're doing the whole square in code. For example, if you're using boarders or outline, you might be cropping slightly, vs using :before and :after to make child squares.

Comment: Sure, I just edited the question with the link to a demo.

Comment: Ahh yeah. Few ideas on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome