# CSS transform rotate pixel issue in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to create swing button with transform rotate property ,
It's works fine in opera and chrome browsers but in firefox its create weird pixel issue in the border of the button:

[image: Button rendering in Firefox]

My css code for button & swing keyframes

```css
.RedButton {
  background-color: #bc0000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #bc0000;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  animation: swing 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: swing 5s infinite;
  transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
  20%,
  60% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  40%,
  80% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swing {
  20%,
  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  40%,
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="RedButton">Get Started Now!</div>
```

Am i missing something ?

Comment: I have try your code it's all ok [Photo](https://ibb.co/Qrxt7Zb) - Firefox 77.0.1 -  Win 10

Comment: May be helpful to add the version of Firefox you are running on and your OS ;)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I'm using the exact same FF version as yours, but the anti- aliasing looks horrible (just like OP's): https://i.imgur.com/Gr8GDAf.mp4

Comment: @Terry how is possible :0?

Comment: @Temani Afif answer makes it much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding a tiny shadow make it look better:

```css
.RedButton {
  background-color: #bc0000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #bc0000;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff ;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  animation: swing 5s infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #bc0000;
}


@keyframes swing {
  20%,
  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  40%,
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="RedButton">Get Started Now!</div>
```

Comment: Not 100% fixed but make it much much better , tnx mate!

Comment: @domikp you can still increase it a little more (2px)

Comment: Yep i know , tnx Bro !

Answer (score -1):

`backface-visibility` seems to do the work according to this SO thread: [css transform, jagged edges in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome)

```
.RedButton {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   // ...
}
```

If this does not work, try: `outline: 1px solid transparent;`

Comment: did you try it? also the question you linked is about Chrome and no Firefox

Comment: In the thread people talk about having this issue on Firefox @TemaniAfif

Comment: @geauser , not working , but box-shadow make it much better. 
tnx for your answer.