# Menu item underline shrinks vertically at the end of hover state

Tags: html, css

I am having hard time to understand why **underline** is shrinking at the end of hovering state (small vertical shrink). Code itself is simple and there shouldn't be anything that shrinks this *pseudo* element. The same thing is happening in this editor. But, this effect isn't happening on *Mozilla* for example. So my question is: Am I missing something or is this something *Google chrome* has with?

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.main-header{
    background-color: var(--menu-header-background);
    top: var(--header_height);
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.small-header{
    height: var(--header_height);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header-container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
header .navigation a li{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: inherit;
}
#main-menu li:hover{
    color: blue;
    transition: .4s;
}
#main-menu a{
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: transform .25s;
}
#main-menu li:hover::after{
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <ul class="navigation" id="main-menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>about me</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>contact me</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between Chrome and FF. Looks fine to me

Comment: Show a screenshot of the problem, pls

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem but I think it is because you are using trasition

Comment: I see the diff. Underline is about 2px thick then flattens to ~1px.

Comment: @wazz there it is

Comment: Something to do with the height in `#main-menu li::after`. 1px and 3px don't change, but 2px does.

Comment: Which Chrome Browser version are you using?

Comment: @DeniJ. Latest (88.0.4324.104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug about transform. Adding a dummy box-shadow and `will-change: transform` will fix the bug.

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.main-header{
    background-color: var(--menu-header-background);
    top: var(--header_height);
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.small-header{
    height: var(--header_height);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header-container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
header .navigation a li{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: inherit;
}
#main-menu li:hover{
    color: blue;
    transition: .4s;
}
#main-menu a{
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: transform .25s;
    /* added */
    will-change: transform;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
#main-menu li:hover::after{
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <ul class="navigation" id="main-menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>about me</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>contact me</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

<sup>My refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65132846/10698741)</sup>

Comment: Thanks man, never would have figured it out myself. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the line underneath the menu-item shrinks because when you hover the menu item, it changes the scaleX from 0 to 1:

from:`transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);`
to: `transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);`

and you have transition property on transform because of which the line shrinks smoothly.

It is not working on Mozilla Firefox because you haven't added any [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). You need to add prefixes to both transition and transform properties to ensure maximum compatibility.

Try using these in your style:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header{
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.main-header{
    background-color: var(--menu-header-background);
    top: var(--header_height);
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.small-header{
    height: var(--header_height);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.63);
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header-container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: inherit;
}
header .navigation a li{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: inherit;
}
#main-menu li:hover{
    color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    -o-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
#main-menu a{
    position: relative;
}
#main-menu li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
            transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
    transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
    -o-transition: transform .25s;
    transition: transform .25s;
    transition: transform .25s, -webkit-transform .25s;
}
#main-menu li:hover::after{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
            transform: translateX(-50%) scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it looks like it's not about vendor. Still same effect