# Weird artifact from rotated border in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, transform

So I have a border that is basically a half circle but rotated slightly. It looks fine in firefox but in chrome it has a thin line on the part of the border that should be transparent. If the element is **not** rotated it looks **good in chrome** and does not have the artifact appear. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#line {
  border: 7px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border-color: #000 #000 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #000;
  margin: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg)
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

and then here is what it looks like: [in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRDO5.png), [in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHar9.png)

Comment: Jagged is always a product of rotation, Firefox seem to handle it better than chrome, you could do with `border-bottom-width:0;` to fix the Firefox issue

Comment: Have you tried adding `outline: 0` as well?

Comment: I did try `outline` but not luck

Comment: You can remove the antialiasing artifact by adding `translateZ(0px)` after the rotate, but you still won't have the same linecap as Firefox... Anyway, this can be seen as a bug in Chrome, you should not have to force GPU rendering for it to not produce artifacts, so go to https://crbug.com to report it.

Comment: @kaiido that did in fact work and I should definitely do that thanks for the suggestion and the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this property to the `#line`:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This isn't exactly what this property usually used for, but it seems to help with fixing other odd transform associated rendering issues on Chrome such as jagged edges.

Source: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6898097/13172018)

Comment: This did clear up the issue thanks for the help @tiffachoo