# transform: rotate makes my element not be as smooth

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how to explain what I mean, but here's a photo so you can see:
[image: photo]

The part in the circle is not really as smooth as I'd like. I have a multiple monitor setup and on another monitor the not-smoothness is really annoying. Is there any way to make it look better?

```css
#dashboard-content {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0 rgba(47, 91, 234, 0.125);
}

.avatar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #3f43fd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar-wrapper::after {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: -45px;
  left: -25%;
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.dashboard-avatar {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
}

.dashboard-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  row-gap: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.dashboard-name {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard-email {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: gray;
}

.dashboard-line {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  margin: 0.2rem auto 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #3f43fd;
  content: "";
}

.fa-diamond-custom {
    color: #b9f2ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-content">
    <div class="avatar-wrapper"><img class="dashboard-avatar" src="https://pluspng.com/img-png/png-user-icon-circled-user-icon-2240.png" alt="test"></div>
    <div class="dashboard-data">
        <div class="dashboard-name">Octavian Niculescu<div class="dashboard-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-email">octavian.niculescu@test.com</div>
        <div class="dashboard-diamonds">100<i class="fa fa-diamond fa-diamond-custom" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suspect there might be some anti-aliasing setting that might help with this, but I couldn't find any.

So, what would be the best way to make that line as smooth as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: google "css rotate antialiasing".
You'll get a lot of input on this issue. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome

Comment: @Lalalena I couldn't find anything helping in my case. I'm using Firefox 95.

Answer (score 1):

Use the blur feature to smooth the image as you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur()

And then use a mask to hide the space that you don't want the effect to appear.

You can read this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

For more examples: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mask-image.asp

Comment: Maybe give an example in your answer instead of just links?

Comment: This is too complex for me

Answer (score -1):

```css
#dashboard-content {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 1rem 0 rgba(47, 91, 234, 0.125);
}

.avatar-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  background-color: #3f43fd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar-wrapper::after {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 90%;
  left: -25%;
  content: "";
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.dashboard-avatar {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dashboard-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  row-gap: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.dashboard-name {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard-email {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: gray;
}

.dashboard-line {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  margin: 0.2rem auto 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #3f43fd;
  content: "";
}

.fa-diamond-custom {
    color: #b9f2ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-content">
    <div class="avatar-wrapper"><img class="dashboard-avatar" src="https://pluspng.com/img-png/png-user-icon-circled-user-icon-2240.png" alt="test"></div>
    <div class="dashboard-data">
        <div class="dashboard-name">Octavian Niculescu<div class="dashboard-line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-email">octavian.niculescu@test.com</div>
        <div class="dashboard-diamonds">100<i class="fa fa-diamond fa-diamond-custom" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work - still looks jagged, and the line doesn't look as before on 1920x1080 (as it looked in my photo)