# CSS: Heavily aliased 3d-rotated text

Tags: html, css, antialiasing

Please take a look at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/stefanpl-the-sasster/pen/WNgyKBL).

The more the text gets in the background, the more aliasing occurs.

Screenshot, taken in chrome on macOS (looks the same in FF & Safari):

[image: heavy aliasing occurring on css 3d-rotated text]

I've tried different values for `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `text-rendering`, slapped `translate3d(0,0,0)` around and some more strange voodoo. Nothing makes for a nice result. With a little `filter: blur` I can cover up the problem, obviously sacrificing sharpness.

Is this an inevitability of life (because displays have pixels), or can something be done about it?

###### Code from codepen for future reference

```css
body {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 6vw;
  transform: rotate3d(1, -0.4, -0.4, 250deg);
}
```

```html
html
<div>
  <h1> Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you put your code into your question (so your question is useful for future readers when  your codepen disappears).

Comment: I tried a couple of these without any success, but you might be able to find something useful in here: [css transform, jagged edges in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just how browsers render it. If you really want to get rid of it, just try a completely different approach with another transformation. ://

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of the browser, you can only reduce the over sharpness by reducing the font size and scaling the text by transform. The more you scale it the more it smoothens until it becomes blur.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 5vw;
  transform: rotate3d(1, -0.4, -0.4, 250deg) scale(4);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```